# How to bind RadGrid calendar close?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

I am using `telerik RadGrid`.
How I can bind calendar close event in jQuery.
I tried it but it doesn't work.

```
var popup = self._datePicker._getPopup();

popup.add_popupClosing(function () {
    alert("here we are!");
});
```

I want to bind something on calendar popup close.

Comment: Please check client events in the calender control.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the self variable is, but you should make sure you have proper references to the IScriptControl object you are trying to use. Here is a small sample that will loop across all datepickers, get their control and use some API:

```
    <telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="rdp1"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="rdp2"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad()
    {

        $telerik.$(".RadPicker input:first-child").each(function (index, elem)
        {

            if (elem && elem.control && elem.control.add_popupClosing)
                elem.control.add_popupClosing(theDesiredHandler);
        });
    }

    function theDesiredHandler(sender, args)
    {
        alert("date picker with ID: " + sender.get_id() + "is closing its popup");
    }
</script>
```

This will let you use some jQuery selectors to get only specific children or sometihng like that.

OR this way to get all pickers on the page:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $telerik.radControls.length; i++)
            {
                if (Telerik.Web.UI.RadDatePicker.isInstanceOfType($telerik.radControls[i]))
                    $telerik.radControls[i].add_popupClosing(theDesiredHandler);
            }
```

Comment: I'm not using RadDatePicker controller directly. I'm using it inside RadGrid. I also added                                                      self._datePicker = $find(e.attr("id") + '_gdtcSharedCalendar');
            self._datePicker.add_dateClick(function (sender, ev) {
                alert("something")
            });                                                        and that works (self is my 'radGrid') but when i tried to add    self._datePicker.add_popupClosing(self.theDesiredHandler);             it says "Object doesn't support property or method 'add_popupClosing'"

Comment: Look through your DOM traversal and make sure you use the correct objects. With jquery it will be fairly easy to get the pickers that are children of the grid so you can attach events (see my first sample).